# TIFF alpha channel glows on edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, transparency

When I try to use an image that has an alpha channel, the image has glowing around the parts where there is transparency. Below are images to better explain my issue. Both are using the same image with exactly the same node setup and Cycles render engine.

In Blender 2.90.1 it looks like this:
[image: In Blender 2.90.1 it looks like this]

and in Blender 2.79 it works as expected:
[image: Blender 2.79]

This is the image i'm using. It is a TIF file created in Photoshop
[image: Blender 2.79]

Is this a bug or has something changed in the way alpha is handled?
I haven't used 2.90.1 version for long as I only recently updated from 2.79

EDIT: After packing the TIFF file into the blend file, the glowing disappeared. Then after unpacking the image and adding it to a new image texture node, the  glowing appeared again.

Looks like Blender 2.90.1 treats external and packed files differently.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). What happens if you plug the alpha channel directly into the Alpha input of Pricipled BSDF? And don't use the mix node?

Comment: Hi. The result is the same.

Comment: I would suspect that for some reason the input values are larger than 1.0. Could you try to add a *Map Range* node with *Clamp* enabled between the Image node and the Principled BSDF? Does the glow also occur when only the color is connected?

Comment: I added the _map range_ node with clamp enabled. The texture turned grayscale as expected but I could still see the glow around the holes like before (just not so bright as it was only grayscale). I also tried to connect the texture _color_ to the Principled BSDF and disconnected the alpha socket of the _texture node_ completely, after that the glow disappeared along with the transparent holes.

Comment: Photoshop has completely bungled alpha. All of Blender’s eight bit imports are unassociated, so I suspect it might be interpreting the TIFF incorrectly as unassociated alpha and it is associated? On the upside, Blender *finally* displays alpha properly thanks to @atmind.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got the versions mixed up big time. I corrected the question now. I also downloaded 2.91.0 Alpha from builder.blender.org and tried my blend file there but the behaviour is still the same as 2.90.1; there is no glow when using a packed image but after extracting and re-adding the image as an external image, the glow appears again.

Comment: @troy_s Now I'm going to be interested what is going on with TIFF when packed into a blend (that is fine), but unpacked issue is back. Why blender reads same data differently? Thank you

Comment: As @troy_s sugested, it's important to determine first whether the TIFF has an associated or unassociated alpha (the format allows both, although Photoshop internals are unassociated).
If alpha is misinterpreted, you'll get either double association (dark fringe) or a misplaced division (producing those glowing artifacts). Older blender versions used to assume that 8 bit RGBA images were always unassociated sRGB, usually matching the output from Photoshop. Blender 2.91 might have changed that.

Comment: Leaving aside changes that Blender 2.91 might have introduced, it's important to note that Photoshop offers different and incosistent ways of saving a TIFF: If you keep layer masks in your source image, it will save unassociated no matter what. If you apply the masks, it will associate if you mark the save transparency checkbox in the exporter, and save something that Blender won't interpret as RGBA if you don't.

Comment: Also important: keep in mind that Photoshop apparently associates alpha when you mark the Save Transparency checkbox ONLY when you're not using layers/masks.
When you keep masks, the resulting tiff will still be unassociated (straight).

Answer (score 1):

*With image packaged into blend it works for me as expected. The issue appears when TIFF is unpacked and used linked from directory. Troy_s probably will be able to explain the issue, I don't have a knowledge in this area. I can just say how to avoid the issue here.*

---

- your TIFF doesn't use Transparency but channel "Alpha" (that is also why option "Save Transparency" is grey when you are saving your TIFF

[image]

- to avoid the issue copy alpha channel and paste into Mask channel for "Background" layer.

[image]

- Then when you save with "Layers", "Save Transparency" is available.

[image]

- This TIFF is rendered fine in Blender.

[image]

Comment: Here is an image of my TIFF save options: [imgur](https://i.imgur.com/1sZlT9F.png) the save transparency option is grayed out for some reason but the "Save alpha channels" option is enabled in the "Save as" window that appears before the TIFF options window. Color space is RGB and bit depth is 8bit.

Comment: I attached the blend file to the question now.

Comment: This method worked and now the transparency works in Blender. Though its weird that saving the image from photoshop and using the _alpha channel_ instead of a layer mask works when the image is packed into the blend file. This sounds like a bug and should be looked into.

Comment: As Troy_s commented it can be on Photoshop side, I don't really know how these things works. Also Robert's comment is right, there is RGB larger than 1. So it is definitely clear Alpha channel participates on  RGB appearance. I'm more curious how blender handles packed  TIFF without issue ... :)

Comment: I might be wrong here but it seems like Blender treats the alpha channel of external images as premultiplied alpha regardless of what has been chosen in the properties panel. If you read [here in the Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/image_settings.html#common-options) it says that premultiplied alpha is useful for emissive effects and that sounds like what is happening here with RGB larger than 1, causing the glowing effect.

Comment: It used to be the other way around. Blender used to assume that 8bit images with alpha were unassociated, which made dealing with associated tiffs problematic.
Maybe (and I'm just speculating because I'm not using 2.91) Blender finally does the right thing and reads the tiff Metadata to pick the proper association instead of assuming it's unassociated. That would mean that an unproperly tagged image coming from Photoshop might break.

Comment: Another possibility is that they changed the tiff importer to assume it's always associated, which would result in missing a multiplication when an unassociated file is loaded.
If the texture's alpha dropdown doesn't do anything when you switch from premultiplied to straight that might be the problem.
Again, pure speculation. You need to figure out first whether the Tiff file is correct and whether alpha is associated or not.

Comment: I'm thinking that the only way you can see those glowing edges is that you feed unassociated to the shader and interpret it as associated (skipping multiplication). But in your screenshots we can see that your alpha is set to straight.
If the file is actually unassociated, then it's clearly a bug, but you have to make sure that the file is right.

Comment: I changed the Alpha dropdown to _channel packed_ and that got rid of the glowing effect when using external image. How can I figure out if the Tiff file is correct?

Comment: @nyaol9 if your intention is to use a texture with transparency, ignore the "channel packed" option. It's intended for something else.
There are two methods of encoding alpha: One is as a separate mask. We call that "Unasociated alpha", because alpha is completely independent of RGB. It is also often called "straight" or unpremultiplied". 
How do you tell an image is unassociated? Pixels that should be completely transparent show colour in the RGB channels, therefore the alpha channel has to be multiplied to the RGB channels don't contribute any colour.

Comment: The other method (which Blender produces when it renders a 3D scene) is "associated" (often called premultiplied). There's a relationship between RGB emissions and alpha. Completely transparent pixels will be black in the RGB channels as they don't contribute any light, but you may find colored pixels that are supposed to be transparent but still contribute light (light fire, glows, light beams, etc.). In an associated alpha image, if you inspect the RGB channels of pixels that should be completely transparent, you'll find black.

Comment: So the way to tell if your image file is whether Associated or unassociated is to figure out if RGB is tied to RGB: If it doesn't, and it has to be masked to be used, then it's unassociated (straight). If it's ready to be composited and transparent pixels don't add any light where they shouldn't, they are associated.
Keep that in mind to choose the right alpha type in Blender and you should be fine, unless there is a bug.

Comment: @Gez I really appreciate your insight, but as you can see these comments are character limited, for a reason. Please delete your comments and summarise them into structured answer. Thank you for your help to keep site readable.

Comment: @vklidu I didn't provide an anwser yet because it's not clear whether the behavior is caused by a Blender's bug or not. I tried to guide the OP so s/he can figure out the source of the problem instead. I don't think it's completely clear yet. If you think that my answers are clear enough to solve the problem, feel free to summarize my comments into an answer and I'll delete these comments.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos is it possible to move it to chat? Would it be accesable to user with a low credit?